# Bootstrap Media Object Image Resizing Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The size of the image is much bigger then the heading and the paragraph text.I am trying to create a "comment thread" type of code using bootstrap.Just for reference the comment,image and the title with date should align properly with each other in an imaginary box the way comments are aligned on facebook,youtube.

```
 <div class="col-xs-7"> 
      <div class="media-list">
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="media1.png" alt="Harsh Parikh" class="media-
                    object pull-left">
                </a>
            </div>  
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="media-heading">Harsh Parikh<small><i> October 
                 21,2017</i></small></h4>
                <p class="text-justify">Alphabet Inc. is an American 
                  multinational conglomerate created in a corporate 
                  restructuring of Google on October 2, 2015.</p>

                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="media1.png" alt="Harsh Parikh" 
                             class="media-object pull-left">
                        </a>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Harsh Parikh<small><i> 
                         October 21,2017</i></small></h4>
                        <p class="text-justify">Alphabet Inc. is an American 
                            multinational conglomerate created in a corporate 
                           restructuring of Google on October 2, 2015.</p>

                    </div>

                 </div>
              </div>

          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```